# Using Google Apps Email in CodeIgniter

Tags: email, codeigniter, google-apps

How do I use Google Apps' email services to send mail using the CodeIgniter email class? The email class seems to prefer SMTP, and I was going through the clients Google Apps account. I can't find any place within the Google Apps settings for SMTP. Does anyone know of a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right you don't find it because CodeIgniter uses the "mail" PHP function.

For some reasons only the most drunken PHP core developer knows about - this function do not support SMTP and worse even the admin can't configure SMTP usuage on Unix (it is possible to do this on windows - making the PHP design look even more crazy).

There are a few SMTP libraries out there that can handle SMTP Email, just use them

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/
http://swiftmailer.org/

or the Email classes from the Zend Framework which are uncoupled from the rest so easy to use with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post detailing instructions:
http://joelg.info/sending-email-with-gmail-using-the-codeignite

Extract From link:

> Why send email with Gmail rather than
>   the server's SMTP configuration? There
>   are a number of advantages I see for
>   doing this: Ability to develop locally
>   and test email sending functionality
>   without going to lengths to setup a
>   local mail server. Ability to utilise
>   Google Apps emails to send email from
>   emails which are on your own domain.
>   Ability to have a reference of the
>   mail you send using this method in the
>   "sent" folder on your Gmail account.