# How to send mail using PHP Codeigniter framework and Google App Engine?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, google-app-engine

When I'm trying to send e-mail using Codeigniter PHP framework application hosted on Google App Engine, I'm getting error:

"Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."

According to GAE documentation, e-mail sender is set to valid Gmail account (project owner), I've tried different protocols (smtp, mail and sendmail) but none of them resolved problem.

Here is email.php configuration:

```php
$config = array(
            'protocol'      =>      'mail',
            'smtp_host'     =>      'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_user'     =>      'project_owner_email_address',
            'smtp_pass'     =>      'password',
            'smtp_port'     =>      '465',
            'smtp_crypto'   =>      'ssl',
            'smtp_timeout'  =>      '5',
            'mailtype'      =>      'html',
            'newline'       =>      "\r\n",
            'crlf'          =>      "\r\n",
            'wrapchars'     =>      '60',
            'wordwrap'      =>      TRUE
            );
```

I've tried using native PHP mail() function, which should be supported by GAE, but it doesn't work either. When I'm changing protocols to other than mail, GAE is responding with different errors, so there must be something wrong with configuration.

I'm using Codeigniter e-mail debug function ($this->email->print_debugger()), here is server response:

```html
Date: Mon, 3 Jun 2019 16:19:16 +0200
From: "Blabla" <project_owner_email_address>
Return-Path: <project_owner_email_address>
Reply-To: <project_owner_email_address>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: project_owner_email_address
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5cf52c6470257@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5cf52c647027e"
```

I've checked GAE list of approved and denied headers, none of my headers are on that denied list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Google Apps Email in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515089/using-google-apps-email-in-codeigniter)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. Google App Engine is part of Google Cloud Platform, not Google Apps.